# Using the call stack as a stack data structure

Tags: design, c++

Sometimes, I use the call stack as a data structure. I use local variables as elements on the stack and use the data member of a class to store the top element. When I use this pattern, I feel like I'm doing something a little naughty!

Here's an example of the pattern. The pattern ensures that `break` and `continue` statements jump to the right place even in the presence of nested `while`, `for` and `switch` statements.

```
class StatementVisitor final : public ast::Visitor {
public:
  void visitFlow(ast::Statement *body, llvm::BasicBlock *brake, llvm::BasicBlock *continoo) {
    // Store the old blocks in local variables and push the new blocks.
    llvm::BasicBlock *oldBreak = std::exchange(breakBlock, brake);
    llvm::BasicBlock *oldContinue = std::exchange(continueBlock, continoo);
    // Traverse a statement that might be a block that might have some
    // break or continue statements in it.
    body->accept(*this);
    // Pop the top blocks and restore the previous blocks
    continueBlock = oldContinue;
    breakBlock = oldBreak;
  }

  void visit(ast::For &four) override {
    // ...
    visitFlow(four.body.get(), doneBlock, incrBlock);
    // ...
  }

  void visit(ast::Break &) override {
    // ...
    funcBdr.ir.CreateBr(breakBlock);
    // ...
  }
  void visit(ast::Continue &) override {
    // ...
    funcBdr.ir.CreateBr(continueBlock);
    // ...
  }

private:
  // the blocks that continue and break statements should jump to
  // these are on the top of the stack
  llvm::BasicBlock *continueBlock;
  llvm::BasicBlock *breakBlock;
  FuncBuilder funcBdr;
};
```

I could use a `std::stack<llvm::BasicBlock *>` and I end up with roughly the same amount of code. This pattern probably saves memory and a few heap allocations in `std::stack`. It's so ingrained in my mind (after using it in two other places) that I think of using this before I even realize that I could use a `std::stack`.

Should I avoid using this pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a completely normal pattern for a visitor. Using class fields as the top of a stack that's pushed and popped in the method call chain is a perfectly acceptable solution. It's basically a workaround to the fact that you can't pass extra parameters to a generic visitor.

It's sometimes better to understand it as tracking a visitor's context. If you end up having a lot of state, it might be worth creating a helper to push / pop those values via RAII since you're in C++. You can also consider splitting up your visitor into multiple parts so that you can pass the top of your stack in as a parameter to your new object. That might be desirable if immutability is a concern for your code.

Comment: I wasn't expecting an answer to say "This is a completely normal pattern for a visitor". This gives me a lot of reassurance. "it might be worth creating a helper to push / pop those values via RAII". I hadn't thought of that! That sounds like a pretty cool idea. I think I'm going to try that.

Comment: Yeah, here's a [real-world example in the clang source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/AST/DeclPrinter.cpp). The pretty printer tracks the indentation level in the same way as in your question. I've personally written multiple compilers that include this strategy in one way or another.